# How to show a div when hovering another div using CSS?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a div that contains an `iframe` element that shows a video (song), and another div that shows the lyrics of that song. the div that shows the lyrics is set with `display: none;`. now, i want to show this div (lyrics) when the div that contains the `iframe` element with the video is hovered. **(I'm not allowed to use Javascript, only CSS)**.

What i have:

karaoke.html:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="karaoke" style="top: 30px; left: 30px;">
        <iframe frameborder="0" height="100px" width="180px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="lyrics-w">
        <span class="lyrics">lyrics here</span>
    </div> 
</div>
```

karaoke.css:

```
.main-container {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 600px;
    width: 800px;
    background: #00aaee;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.karaoke {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 140px;
    width: 180px;
    background: #f78a69; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.lyrics-w {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    height: calc(100% - 30px - 30px - 70px - 30px);
    bottom: 30px;
    background: salmon;  
    border-radius: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 260px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.lyrics {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    line-height: 26px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: large;
    color: #454545;
    font-style: italic;
    line-break: auto;
}
.karaoke:hover .lyrics-w {
    display: block;
}
```

The `.karaoke:hover .lyrics-w { display: block; }` should make the div with the class `.lyrics-w` visible (with `display: block;`) when hovering the div with the class `.karaoke`, but for some reason it doesn't. I used many times this kind of code to change CSS attributes of another elements while hovering specific element, and till now it worked well, I don't understand why it doesn't work here. Maybe because `.karaoke` and `.lyrics-w` are independent objects (I mean one is not child of the other)? I don't know.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.karaoke:hover .lyrics-w { display: block; }` use this

```
.karaoke:hover ~.lyrics-w {display: block;}
```

(use a ~ between them)
So your code should be like this

```css
     .main-container {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 600px;
    width: 800px;
    background: #00aaee;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.karaoke {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 140px;
    width: 180px;
    background: #f78a69; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.lyrics-w {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    height: calc(100% - 30px - 30px - 70px - 30px);
    bottom: 30px;
    background: salmon;  
    border-radius: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 260px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.lyrics {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    line-height: 26px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: large;
    color: #454545;
    font-style: italic;
    line-break: auto;
}
.karaoke:hover ~.lyrics-w {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
        <div class="karaoke" style="top: 30px; left: 30px;">
            <iframe frameborder="0" height="100px" width="180px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="lyrics-w">
            <span class="lyrics">lyrics here</span>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

For more info visit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered)